# Redirect only one subfolder of an extenral domain to my localhost with nginx. And rest of the traffic back to the original domain

Tags: redirect, nginx, proxy, server

Let's say there is an existing domain *dummy* with subdomain *their*:

```
http://their.dummy.com
```

There is an URL (and associated sub-URLs) of that *subdomain.domain* that I would like to reroute on my **localhost**.

```
http://their.dummy.com/store
http://their.dummy.com/store/<whatever>...
```

But all the rest of the URLs, back to the original *subdomain.domain*

I created an entry in **/etc/hosts**:

```
127.0.0.1   their.dummy.com
```

And, naively, created a server in nginx:

```
server {
       listen 80;
       server_name their.dummy.com;
       server_name_in_redirect off;

       access_log /var/log/nginx/access-their.dummy.com.log;
       error_log  /var/log/nginx/error-their.dummy.com.log;

       location /store {
              alias /opt/my/store;
              autoindex on;
       }

       location / {
              proxy_set_header Host their.dummy.com;
              proxy_redirect http://their.dummy.com/;
       }    
}
```

This works fine when I want to access: http://their.dummy.com/store

But the other URLs are not redirected to the original domain.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by *original domain*. In your configuration the `server` block represents `their.dummy.com`, so is already handling requests for it. Also, the `proxy` configuration (if that is what you really need) is incomplete. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for more.

Comment: Thanx Richard for the link. By *original domain*, I mean the machine that is originally pointed to by *http://their.dummy.com/store* before I override it in */etc/hosts* to point to my *http://localhost*.

Comment: So your trying to override the location on your personal machine? The problem is that your bowser has one meaning for that DNS name, and you want `nginx` to have another. IDK but a `resolver` statement might allow `nginx` to bypass your `/etc/hosts` file. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) for more.